# Verify method in constructor was called

Tags: java, jmockit

I have a constructor that calls a method, like this:

```
public Foo(boolean runExtraStuff) {
    if (runExtraStuff){
        doExtraStuff();
    }
}
```

The `doExtraStuff()` method is running some additional commands that are not easily mocked themselves (things like database checks to initialize some variables). Perhaps it would be better for the constructor to not do this, but this is the code I have to work with at the moment.

I would like to create a unit test to make sure that `doExtraStuff()` is called when the boolean `runExtraStuff` is true and does not run when the boolean is false. I am using JMockit.

However, I'm not sure how to make this happen. Normally I would use a `Verifications` on a mocked object, but since I am testing the constructor, I can't use a mocked object in this way. So how can I verify that a method within a constructor was called?

Comment: What does `setup()` do? Usually you test the outcome of that.

Comment: Perhaps an aside, but passing in a `runSetup` method into `Foo` feels like a violation of separation of concerns.  Maybe you should consider a `Factory` type design pattern so you can separate out object initialization from setup work?

Comment: In my opinion, the one true job of a constructor is to initialize the fields of a class. Work in a constructor should truly be avoided and is a code-smell as it cannot be easily tested. You could use a factory method that takes a boolean and returns and instance of your class. This has several advantages, one of them being that you can actually unit test the factory method.

Comment: I know how to test that using Junit and Mockito. You would want to verify that setup() was called exactly one time for true and zero times for false, you also need to spy on your Foo and decouple constructor into a private method. Use factory as others mentioned, that's the best way to do it.

Comment: The job of a constructor is to assign valid values to the object's fields.  If `setup()` is required to make the object valid, it should not be conditional.  If it isn't, it should not be called from the constructor.

Comment: @bot In object-oriented programming, a constructor is supposed to initialize the object to a valid state. If that takes significant work, then it's the correct thing to do. For example, consider the java.net.URL class, which has several such constructors; and the JDK has lots of other examples. In the end, constructors are just special initialization methods, which allow us to have `final` instance fields. And in fact, they are just as easy or hard to test as any method is.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede The example `Foo` class in the question is probably just a simplification; in the real world, it's not uncommon to find constructors taking several parameters, where one of them can lead to conditional sub-initializations inside the object. For example, take the `java.net.URL#URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file, URLStreamHandler handler)` constructor, where `handler` can be null or not; when it's not, some extra logic is performed in the constructor. So, I don't see anything inherently wrong with conditionally calling `setup()` from the constructor.

Comment: @Rogério You're right for cases like `URL`.  But `setup()` sounds suspiciously like a method that does the work of the constructor.

Comment: Since there is some confusion about `setup()`, I've renamed it to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough, even if it requires partial mocking:

```
@Test
public void runsSetupWhenRequestedOnFooInitialization()
{
    // Partially mocks the class under test:
    new Expectations(Foo.class) {};

    final Foo foo = new Foo(true);

    // Assuming "setup" is not private (if it is, use Deencapsulation.invoke):
    new Verifications() {{ foo.setup(); }};
}

@Test
public void doesNotRunSetupWhenNotRequestedOnFooInitialization()
{
    new Expectations(Foo.class) {};

    final Foo foo = new Foo(false);

    new Verifications() {{ foo.setup(); times = 0; }};
}
```

Of course, it would probably be better to avoid mocking in a case like this; instead, the test should check the state of the object through getters or other available methods, if at all possible.

Comment: I love the comment that amounts to "test state instead of mocking if possible"

Answer (score 1):

Well, the straightforward answer doesn't use JMockit at all..

in src/main/java/example..

```
package example;

public class Foo {
    private boolean setupRan = false;

    public Foo(boolean runSetup) {
        if (runSetup) setup();
    }

    public void setup() {
        setupRan = true;
    }

    public boolean getSetupRan() {
        return setupRan;
    }
}
```

in src/test/java/example..

```
package example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {

    private Foo testSubject;

    @Test
    public void should_run_setup() {
        testSubject = new Foo(true);
        assertThat(testSubject.getSetupRan()).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_not_run_setup() {
        testSubject = new Foo(false);
        assertThat(testSubject.getSetupRan()).isFalse();
    }

}
```

I'll go out on a limb and guess that you are interested in a partial mock here:

in src/main/java/example..

```
package example;

public class Foo1 {
    public Foo1(boolean runSetup) {
        if (runSetup) setup();
    }

    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("in setup()");
    }
}
```

in src/test/java/example..

```
package example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Foo1Test {

    // hateful partial mocking of test subject!
    @Mocked({"setup()"})
    private Foo1 testSubject;

    @Test
    public void should_run_setup() {
        new Expectations() {{
            testSubject.setup(); // setup() is called
        }};
        testSubject = new Foo1(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_not_run_setup() {
        new Expectations() {{
            testSubject.setup(); times = 0;
        }};
        testSubject = new Foo1(false);
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: Note that you won't see the println output since the method was mocked.
EDIT 2: Set expectations for invocations of testSubject.setup() to times = 0 in second test

Comment: I am not wanting to add a getter and setter for a variable that keeps track of whether the method was run. All methods in the class should be ones used in production. I want all testing stuff to just be in the test class. The partial mocking does seem to work though, but I'll hold off on accepting in case someone comes up with a better answer.

Comment: I assumed as much about not wanting to introduce a sensing variable, so the partial mock made the most sense to me. Obviously, you want to use caution when mocking any part of your test subject, but I think it could be a reasonable enough thing to do in this context. Am sure you know the Expectations are implicitly verified. Hope it helps!